# What are the main meanings of "Bescheid"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

My dictionary gives me that "Bescheid" means "decision" , "notification" and "information"

The one word seems to have different meanings in different contexts. Why is that, and how can I tell them apart?

Comment: What else do you expect from us, if not what dictionaries already tell you?

Comment: I have (hopefully) clarified the question and vote to reopen.

Comment: @HussienChahin: You tell them apart by the context.

Answer (score 4):

1. **Bescheid** = notation about a decision (often in a juridical context)

> Hat ein Unternehmer die gesetzlichen Vorgaben erfüllt, kann er einen behördlichen **Bescheid** beantragen (z. B. Genehmigung oder Lizenz).
>   *When the entrepreneur fulfils the statutory requirements stated by law, they may apply for an administrative **decision** (e.g. a permit or license).*
>
> Dieser im Eilrechtsschutz ergangene **Bescheid** des Oberverwaltungsgerichts Münster zum Stationspreissystem enthält grundlegende Aussagen, die sich auf einer Mittellinie zwischen der Rechtsposition der DB-Infrastrukturbetreiber und der Bundesnetzagentur bewegen.
>   *The **notice** on the station charging system issued in summary proceedings before Münster Higher Administrative Court contains fundamental statements which lie between the legal position of the DB infrastructure managers and the Federal Network Agency.*
>
> Bei positivem Ausgang der Meetingüberprüfung wird eine standardisierte Mitteilung für die Stelle verfasst, die den **Bescheid** der Bezugsanfrage erhalten hat.
>   *If the Meeting-check turns out to be positive, a standardized notification is written for the office that has received the **reply** of the reference inquiry.*

---

2. **Bescheid wissen** = to know (something), to have knowledge

> Ich **weiß** schon **Bescheid**, du brauchst mir nichts erklären.
>   *I already **know**, you do not need to explain.*
>
> Man muss über die Musikgeschichte unseres Landes gut **Bescheid wissen**.
>   *A good **knowledge** of the musical history of our country is essential.*
>
> Dieser Hinweis sollte auch auf der Rückseite der ärztlichen Bescheinigung stehen, so dass Patient und Arzt über ihre Rechte **Bescheid wissen.**
>   *This information should also be given on the back of the medical certificate so that both patients and doctors **are aware** of their rights.*
>
> Die Arbeitnehmer **wissen** über ihre Anwartschaften **Bescheid.**
>   *Workers **know** about their eligibility.*

---

3. **Bescheid geben** = to inform, to let know

> Ich **gebe** dir **Bescheid**, sobald ich fertig bin.
>   *I will **let you know** once I am finished.*
>
> **Gib** mir **Bescheid**, wenn deine Mutter zu Hause ist.
>   ***Let me know*** when your mother is home.
>
> Bevor Sie mit der Wanderung beginnen, müssen Sie immer sehr präzise **Bescheid geben,** welche Route sie gehen wollen.
>   *Always **leave** precise **information** about where you are going and which route you intend to take.*
>
> Wenn möglich **geben** Sie dem Chef Bescheid.
>   *If it is possible please **inform** the boss.*

Comment: Wenn wir hier schon einem Wörterbuch Konkurrenz machen: **Bescheid tun** fehlt noch.

Comment: Er hat mich beleidigt, da habe ich ihm gehörig Bescheid gegeben. (Prügel, Gegenbeleidigung)

Comment: @userunknown: Diese Bedeutung ist aber ganz offenbar nur regional begrenzt gültig. Ich kannte sie bisher nicht.

Comment: Hier https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~jemandem%20Bescheid%20geben%20%2F%20sagen&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou finde ich auch 'jmd. Bescheid stoßen', was ich auch schon mal gelesen/gehört habe, aber wovon ich denke, dass es alt und aussterbend ist. Im Alltag begegnet mir das nicht. Ältere Bücher/Filme vielleicht.

Comment: *jmd. Bescheid stoßen* höre ich wesentlich öfter als *jmd. Bescheid geben*.